# MongoDB - Find accounts that match one field but do not match a second field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

Okay, so I'm trying to identify a list of accounts where they have matching SSN, but DOB is different.

Fields in question are: account_num, ssn, dob. In the end, I need the account_num for those accounts which has more than 1 accounts that match the SSN, but has a different DOB. I hope that makes sense.

I've been trying with something along these lines, but not getting any results...

```
    db.getCollection("accounts").aggregate(
   [
       {"$match" : {"ssn" : { "$exists" : true }}},
       {"$match" : {"ssn" : {"$ne" : [ ]}}},
       {"$group" : {"_id" : {"ssn" : "$ssn"},"count" : {"$sum" : 1}}},
       {"$match" : {"count" : {"$gt" : 1}}},
       {"$group" : {"_id" : {"dob" : "$dob"},"count" : {"$sum" : 1}}},
       {"$match" : {"count" : "1"}},
       {"$project" : {"account_num" : 1,"ssn" : 1,"dob" : 1}}
   ],
   {"allowDiskUse" : true});
```

I can tell that there are flaws in the logic, but just not sure how to go about correcting them. This is just to kind of map out my train of thought. Maybe there's a totally different way to go about this.